# Python - TypeError: descriptor 'axes' for 'BlockManager' objects doesn't apply to 'SingleBlockManager' object

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read a csv file on a new computer (so first time that I use Spyder on this computer) :

```
import pandas as pd
path = "D:/"
test = pd.read_csv(path+"test.csv")
```

I achieved to read this file on my previous computer.

But here, I get this error :

```
TypeError: descriptor 'axes' for 'BlockManager' objects doesn't apply to 'SingleBlockManager' object
```

Does anyone know what's happening ?

Comment: it seems broken pandas, try reinstall it.

Comment: Very strange. Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: in the meantime I reinstalled Anaconda and it works now

Comment: (only pandas not, but with Anaconda it's ok !)

Comment: Reinstalling pandas and restarting python fixed this for me. Thanks @jezrael !